# It wasn’t any time to hesitate. / There was no time to hesitate anymore

Tags: pronouns

It is known that we use "it" for time, distance, day and weather. Why the first sentence is wrong, as I suppose, and there is a need to use "there was" here? [Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=There%20was%20no%20time%2CIt%20was%20no%20time&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=50&direct_url=t4%3B%2CThere%20was%20no%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthere%20was%20no%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20was%20no%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CIt%20was%20no%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bit%20was%20no%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIt%20was%20no%20time%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2CThere%20was%20no%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthere%20was%20no%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20was%20no%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CIt%20was%20no%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bit%20was%20no%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIt%20was%20no%20time%3B%2Cc0) is Ngram about this thing. Because that's a description of some situation? Feel free to provide some examples to explain it if there is a need to use "it was" in some similar context.

> It wasn’t any time to hesitate.
>
> There was no time to hesitate anymore.

Comment: More idiomatically, *It was **no time to** hesitate* for the first version (but both yours and mine are a bit "literary, poetic"). Which doesn't mean *quite* the same thing as your second example. Your first phrasing (and my alternative) both mean something like *Situations **can** arise where it's okay to hesitate, but **this wasn't one of them***. Whereas your second phrasing baldly asserts that ***on this occasion**, no time is available for hesitation*. Very similar, but subtly different implications.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hey, stop peeking into my mind and filching my answers while I write them!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, As I understand it, the following sentences are completely the same in their meaning:
It was a time not to hesitate. 
It was not a time to hesitate. 
It was no time to hesitate.

Comment: @Jeff Morrow, As I understand it, the difference between "It was" & "There was" is that the first one has more literary context, but the second one particularly describies that situation "There was no longer time to hesitate." Right?

Comment: I can't see any reason why the preferred wording should vary depending on whether people should be ***hesitating*** or ***quibbling***, but it's easier to compare prevalence in Google Books with the latter. There are just half-a-dozen hits for [***It was not a time to quibble***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22It+was+not+a+time+to+quibble%22) (and none at all for [***It was a time not to quibble***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22It+was+no+time+to+quibble%22)), but...

Comment: [***It was no time to quibble***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22It+was+no+time+to+quibble%22) gets *dozens* of hits. If you ever encounter either of the less-favoured wordings, I'm sure it would always have the same meaning as the idiomatically established version. But the natives rarely use those alternatives.  Whatever - I'm sure everyone would agree that ***There was no time to quibble*** has a *completely* different meaning.

Comment: @Sergey You have essentially asked a new question as a comment. I cannot answer a question within the restrictions of a comment. I do not agree **AT ALL** that, in general,  “it is” is more literary than “there is,” nor do I think FF implied any such generality. As a rough approximation, i’d say that “it is” has a narrower referent than “there is,” but that there is no sharp dividing line between the two dummy subjects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why I find Ngram to be a dangerous tool. Both “there was no time” and “it was no time” are grammatical and idiomatic, but they have different meanings. Ngram cannot tell you that.

> It was no time to

is referring to time as identifying an event, an occasion, a situation. See item 2 in full definition

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time

So the meaning is

> It was not one of those occasions when

We are talking about an event or situation of a particular type. “Time” in this sense is a countable noun.

> It was not a time

is also perfectly acceptable.

> There was no time

means

> The amount of time was insufficient

Here “time” is referring to a span of physical time, a duration. When used in this sense, “time” is not countable.

> There was time

Now with respect to your two example sentences, I greatly doubt that the first is grammatically wrong, but the word “any” seems odd to me. I’d expect “a” instead.

The second sentence, while grammatical, does not seem completely idiomatic to me. I would write

> There was no longer time to hesitate.

Comment: I never thought of *the word “any” seems odd to me. I’d expect “a” instead.* But once I read those words, I completely agree.